# Design compatability in iOS 8 and below

Tags: ios8, xcode6, autolayout

I am new to iOS 8, Xcode 6. I like to know how to create iPhone portrait application compatible with different inches 4.0,4.7,5.5.

In Xcode 6 storyboard if i select width,height as 'all iPhone portrait mode' i.e 400 x 800 , how it will adopt to other screens.
 
I tried to design for one page it looked good in 5.5 , but not good in other screens.

Do I need to programmatically alter the layouts based on screen ?

Note: I used Resolve Autolayout Issues to create layout for components.

Comment: it depends... because you can even use _autoresize-mask_ for keeping it simple, or you may go for _auto-layout_ if you need a complex solution, but you need to rearrange them programmatically if you want a highly sophisticated for a complex interface. there is no omnipotent solution or advice for that, because it is application- and developer-specific as well; and you need to consider about the future maintenance's time as the application is usually not done when you release a version of it.

Comment: so which one i need to choose?

Comment: it is nearly impossible to tell, I guess there is just not enough information of the project here, but even if anyone tells you their own opinion, you are the project's developer eventually, so you need to choose the most comfortable way for you to do it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559847/autolayout-just-not-working-for-every-screen-size/29562607#29562607

Comment: Ya thank you @holex..@Asadullah Ali your's concept is ok to me..but UI look is important in this application..If all pages comes in scrollview,it will not be good..